# Can INSERT return an ID that is not auto incremented in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql-insert

I have an database  that looks like this

```
int groupId
int msgId
data
```

where the primary key is made up of groupId+msgId, for example some keys are 1-1, 1-2, 1-3, 2-1, 2-2, 2-3 and so on

so when inserting a new value it's made like this

```
INSERT INTO chatMessages (msgId, groupId, ...) 
SELECT MAX(msgId)+1, ?, ... 
FROM chatMessages 
WHERE chatMessages.groupId = ?
```

To have my own autoincrement sort of say where sequence numbers play out nicely in each group.

Now when I insert a new message is there any way I can get `msgId` without doing two seperate requests? (like auto_increment id's would be retreivable)

Thank you

Comment: Why is it so important to have different/separate counter for each group exactly?

Comment: just for convenience so it's easy to find out how many unread messages etc (the last message is passed on for each group and the client keeps track of lastRead message, this way it's easy to figure out how many unread messages you have in each room without having to query the server for the number of messages between lastReadId and the latest message). I guess other solutions are possible too but if it's possible to do it like this I thought it would be elegant (and push my knowledge of MySQL)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a user-defined variable:

```
INSERT INTO chatMessages (msgId, groupId, ...) 
SELECT @last_msgId := MAX(msgId)+1, ?, ... 
FROM chatMessages 
WHERE chatMessages.group = ?
```

Then you can use `@last_msgId` in following queries in the same MySQL connection, similar to the way you would use `LAST_INSERT_ID()` with normal auto-increment.

Comment: Thank you Barmar! But I would still have to do a "select @last_msgId" to get the value right? (resulting in two queries and longer time). (What I'm trying to do is somehow try to use @GetGeneratedKeys or similar in jdbi to get the id of the message)

Comment: If you need to get it into a variable in the client language, you'll need to do a second query. But you can just use it directly in other queries without retrieving it first, e.g. `INSERT INTO otherTable ... VALUES (@last_msgId, ...)`

Comment: There's no way to return any value directly while doing a DDL query.